# Is there a built-in function in MATLAB to get bsxfun(@rdivide,abs(X),sum(abs(X)))?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

It is a column normalizaton. For example,

```
X=  1 -1 -2
    1  4 -8
```

`bsxfun(@rdivide,abs(X),sum(abs(X)))` will get

```
ans = 0.5 0.2 0.2 
      0.5 0.8 0.8
```

Comment: There is not. What's wrong with what you have written?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function to shorten your code, like [Suever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670206/suever) commented already. However, since MATLAB R2016b there is [implicit expansion](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#bu90yi3-1), also called broadcasting in other numerical languages/packages. This means your code can be shortened to `abs(X)./sum(abs(X))`.

For the sake of explicitness the use of `bsxfun` is better, although it can be more difficult to understand for those who don't know MATLAB. Implicit expansion is...implicit, though, which may lead to incorrect behaviour where you (or a reader of your code) assumes a different result or an error.

Comment: Can't we just stick to *broadcasting* as a term? Octave, NumPy, Eigen and others have been using it for quite some time already.

Comment: We could, but I don't use Octave, NumPy, Eigen and others, so I didn't know they support this too and that it was called broadcasting, therefore I did not use the word. Besides, this question is about MATLAB. I'll edit my answer to add the term. Furthermore, 'implicit expansion' is the name The MathWorks use for broadcasting.

Comment: *For the sake of explicitness the use of bsxfun is better*… well, the Mathworks link you posted says *Compared to using bsxfun, implicit expansion offers faster speed, better memory usage, and improved readability of code*, so who are we to argue?

Comment: We are to argue, because we are the end users. Besides, who are they to force us? After all, they offer both `bsxfun` and implicit expansion. Of course, in this case there are a lot of reasons in favour of implicit expansion, but if we aren't interested in speed, memory usage and code readability, we *can* argue in favour of `bsxfun`! ;)